# jarsigner verification fails

Tags: java, jarsigner

Using freshly installed JDK 1.7 we sign the JAR file. Immediately after that we verify it using the same jarsigner and the same keystore and ... it fails with the message:

> invalid SHA256 hash on ...

The signing/verification code is trivial (two consequent lines in windows batch):

```
%JAVADIR%\jarsigner -keystore \path\to\SBBJavaCodeSigningStore -storepass my_password SecureBlackbox.JCE.jar sbbjavacodesigningkey
%JAVADIR%\jarsigner -verify -keystore \path\to\SBBJavaCodeSigningStore -storepass my_password SecureBlackbox.JCE.jar
```

The worst thing is that the problem seems to be random, and jarsigner doesn't even set errorlevel (exit code) when verification fails.

Is it a bug of Java signer or cryptographic classes or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am putting the solution here as a lesson for other users.

It appeared that later in batch file we batch-signed all JARs and this particular JAR gets signed twice. jarsigner lets you do the second signature and breaks the first one this way.